# specifying aws ECS/Fargate container dependency fails to deply

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-cdk

I got the below code using aws-cdk Python language but is failing to deploy, with redis_container not available error, what am I doing wrong, I want redis container to start first and then the rest. maybe my understanding of the container dependency is not correct??

```
        ecs_redis_task = ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(self,
        id = 'redis',
        cpu=512,
        memory_limit_mib =1024
        )

        redis_container = ecs_redis_task.add_container(id = 'redis_container',
        image = img_.from_ecr_repository(repository=repo_, tag='redis_5.0.5')
              )

        redis_container.add_port_mappings({
            'containerPort' : 6379
        })

        redis_dependency = ecs.ContainerDependency(container = redis_container, condition = ecs.ContainerDependencyCondition.HEALTHY)

        ecs_webserver_task = ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(self,
        id = 'webserver',
        cpu=256,
        memory_limit_mib =512
        )

        webserver_container = ecs_webserver_task.add_container(id = 'webserver_container',
        image = img_.from_ecr_repository(repository=repo_, tag='airflow_1.10.9')
       )

        webserver_container.add_port_mappings({
            'containerPort' : 8080
        })

        webserver_container.add_container_dependencies(redis_dependency)
```

If I remove the dependency code, it deploys fine!

Error:

```
12/24 | 2:46:51 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition                    | webserver (webserverEE139216) Cannot depend on container + 'redis_container' because it does not exist (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ClientException; Request ID: 81828979-9e65-474e-ab0e-b163168d5613)
```

Comment: Whats the exact error

Comment: added the error, it does not offer much

Comment: This is a circular dependency which is not allowed.

Comment: @shariqmaws  can you please point out where the circular dependency is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this code and it works as expected adding the dependency in the Task definition, only thing changed from your code is the image [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs.README.html):

```
from aws_cdk import (
    #aws_s3 as s3,
    aws_ecs as ecs,
    core
)

class HelloCdkStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        #bucket = s3.Bucket(self,  "MyFirstBucket", versioned=True,)

        ecs_redis_task = ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(self, id='redis', cpu=512, memory_limit_mib=1024)
        redis_container = ecs_redis_task.add_container(id = 'redis_container', image=ecs.ContainerImage.from_registry("amazon/amazon-ecs-sample"),)
        redis_container.add_port_mappings({
            'containerPort' : 6379
        })

        redis_dependency = ecs.ContainerDependency(container = redis_container, condition = ecs.ContainerDependencyCondition.HEALTHY)

        ecs_webserver_task = ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(self, id='webserver', cpu=256, memory_limit_mib=512)
        webserver_container = ecs_webserver_task.add_container(id = 'webserver_container', image=ecs.ContainerImage.from_registry("amazon/amazon-ecs-sample"),)
        webserver_container.add_port_mappings({
            'containerPort' : 8080
        })

        webserver_container.add_container_dependencies(redis_dependency)
```

CloudFormation after cdk synth:

```
 "webserverEE139216": {
      "Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
      "Properties": {
        "ContainerDefinitions": [
          {
            "DependsOn": [
              {
                "Condition": "HEALTHY",
                "ContainerName": "redis_container"
              }
            ],
            "Essential": true,
            "Image": "amazon/amazon-ecs-sample",
            "Name": "webserver_container",
            "PortMappings": [
              {
                "ContainerPort": 8080,
                "Protocol": "tcp"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
```

Comment: Thank to your answer, I was able to resolve the issue, 
looks like there is an issue with ecr.Repository.from_repository_name()
it  was not returning the proper reference:
arn looks like
`arn:${Token[AWS::Partition.3]}:ecr:${Token[AWS::Region.4]}:${Token[AWS::AccountId.0]}:repository/airflow
`

changed it to ecr.Repository.from_repository_arn()
now the reference works properly.
`arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:repository/airflow
`